# What is the best way to analyse data from a .sql file without a connection to a database?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I need to analyse data, without a database engine, from a .sql file that contains only 2 types of commands that create relational tables (i.e CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO). I'm not sure how i can analyse the data without connecting to a database.

For example, the Python module sqlite3, required you to connect to .db.

Below is an example of the commands within the .sql file. Any ideas would be appreciated!

```
CREATE TABLE `sales` (
  `month` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `quarter` varchar(30) collate latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `year` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `sales` decimal(10,4) NOT NULL,
  `cost` decimal(10,4) NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci;
```

Comment: so write/find an sql parser, and implement your own database engine, basically...

Comment: What do you want to analyse? Could be anything, like the type storage engine. For such things, tools like grep would work just fine.

Comment: @Fang I want to analyze the data that these relational tables would have if the commands were executed. The .sql file contains a number of INSERT INTO commands containing the data I want to analyze. I will check out grep, Thank You!

Comment: SQLite doesn't require you to "connect", just open a file. And you actually [don't even need to do that](https://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html).

Comment: @Blorgbeard even better! Thanks